# Path Constraint deforming Mesh

Tags: mesh, path

I just finished the walking cycle for a Horse inspired model and tried to apply the Follow Path Constraint which caused a weird behaviour:
The armature follows the path but the mesh stays put, deforming more and more as the armature moves away from its starting point...
[image: Mesh deforming]

What am I missing?

Comment: this depends too much on your model, I suggest you to upload it for others to check and perhaps fix (eg: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Answer (score 1):

for stability I don't allow bones to follow paths.  Instead I use an 'Empty' or dummy invisible 2D plane and parent the main armature to that, then have the dummy follow the path.  You could try that.

It's an easy matter to vary the main armature's attitude/rotation/pitch etc without having to worry about any interaction the path constraint might have.  I don't recall ever having problems varying individual bone movements either.